# Pegar linhas de uma tabela por um valor com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Possuo uma tabela, com um `select`, em cada linha, e ao clicar em um botão quero pegar todos os itens da tabela onde o `select option` esteja com valor.

```
<table id="myTable">
<span class="result"></span>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option class="op" value="0">-- Selecione --</option>
                <option class="op" value="1">-- Bloqueado --</option>
                <option class="op" value="2">-- Ativo --</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">-- Selecione --</option>
                <option value="1">-- Bloqueado --</option>
                <option value="2">-- Ativo --</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<span class="status"></span>
<button class="row" id="btnAdicionar" type="button" >Adicionar</button>
```

**Como eu consigo *varrer* essa minha tabela e pegar todos os itens que estejam com o select diferente de 0** ?

Comment: Mostre o que você já fez...

Comment: @GabrielKatakura já coloquei o código, não tenho ideia de como fazer no jquery.

Comment: `$("#myTable option[value!="0"]")`, isso vai selecionar todos os elementos com valores diferentes de "0"..

Comment: @MarllonNasser mas como eu pego o valor? Por exemplo, quero dizer que se a linha do ABC esta com status BLOQUEADO. Como eu passo linha por linha, dizendo essa ta ativa, essa ta bloqueada... ?

Comment: vc quer todos os valores, de todas as linhas, que tenham o status diferente de bloqueado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
$('#btnAdicionar').on('click', function() {
    // gera coleção jQuery, converte para nativa com ".get()"
    var selectsAtivos = $('select').filter(function() {
        return this.value == '2';
    }).get();

    // usando array nativa
    var tds = selectsAtivos.reduce(function(arr, el) {
        var tr = $(el).closest('tr'); // aqui procura o "tr" pai do select
        return arr.concat(tr.find('td').get()); // aqui vai buscar os "td" que estão dentro do "tr" que encontrámos na linha de cima
    }, []);
    $(tds).css('color', 'red'); // só para o exemplo, aqui mudam de côr os selecionados.
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3zfLo10c/

Answer (score 2):

```
<table id="myTable">
<span class="result"></span>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option class="op" value="0">-- Selecione --</option>
                <option class="op" value="1">-- Bloqueado --</option>
                <option class="op" value="2">-- Ativo --</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">-- Selecione --</option>
                <option value="1">-- Bloqueado --</option>
                <option value="2">-- Ativo --</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
<span class="status"></span>
<button class="row" id="btnAdicionar" type="button" >Adicionar</button>
```

> Abaixo criamos uma simples linha de busca pelo campo retornando value diferente de 0
>   **Jquery**

```
var names = $("select > option[value!=0]").text();

$(".status").text(names);
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L56c6gss/)

Comment: não funciona, este exemplo ele ta pegando TODOS os itens do select, e não somente os que estão selecionados.